# Using the new error handling in React for application error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to use the new error handling introduced in React 16 in order to handle application errors, like validation errors.

Or should I keep this only for unexpected errors like generic JavaScript exceptions?

Here's more information about error handling in React 16:
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Comment: do you mean `throw` error when invalid email or password was entered and let the boundary component catch and render some message?

Comment: Yes, something like that. To me it feels a bit inappropriate to handle generic errors this way, but I would like a second opinion on this.